# Fetching razorpay payment details

Tags: node.js, api, razorpay

How I can fetch razorpay payment details and place that details in my own coded HTML view file.
I am using Node.js as server side language.

Comment: Have you tested this https://www.npmjs.com/package/razorpay module?

Comment: Payment details of what? Have you [checked the documentation?](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form)